# Generated Flash instance not including all MovieClips

Tags: flash, movieclip, instances

I have a flash based video player that playlists and some other features.
The thing is that when I compile the player, the instances to the updated features dose not get all the latest updates.

it look something like this

```
Player.swf
|
|-Playlist.swf
|-Texts.swf
```

So if I updated the "Texts" with new MovieClips/graphics to be used it wont show up in the "Players" own instance of "Texts". Not even if I recompile the Player. How can this be?

If I run and look at how the Text is set up by using FlashFireBug i can clearly se all MovieClips are there and should probably be loaded.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of not working with this issue, I got an idea that could have something to do with this problem. And it it solved the problem.

The problem is that there is a web-service that is used for loading these children for this player. And as they still wear looking and loading the URL paths for the child SWF files that is set for what is currently published. The rong version of SWFs wear loaded. so by fixing this URL issue problem was solved.

So, recompiling the parent SWF has nothing much to with the compiled child SWF.